# Duplicate record in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jO8Qr.png)I have created a view `CONTRACT_View`. When I'm running view with `table2.objid = 528770`, I'm getting correct record.

As it's a view, I have to use this view in query, and when I'm trying, I get lots of duplicate records.

While running view with ID:

And when using view in query getting diffent record:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRwmv.png)

My view:

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[CONTRACT_View] 
AS
    WITH mycte (OBJID,CONTRACT__TITLE,INCIDENT__ID) AS 
    (
        SELECT  
            table1.Coulmn1 OBJID, 
            table1.title CONTRACT__TITLE,
            table2.objid INCIDENT__ID
        FROM 
            table1 
        INNER JOIN 
            table2 on table2Rel= table1.objid
        WHERE
            (     
               AND (table2.objid=528770               
            )    
    )
    SELECT  
        STUFF((SELECT ',' + CAST(CONTRACT__TITLE AS VARCHAR(2000))
               FROM mycte t2
               WHERE t2.[objid] = t1.[objid]
               FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '') AS [AVILABLE_ENTITLEMENT],
        [INCIDENT__ID]
    FROM 
        mycte t1
    GROUP BY 
        t1.[objid], t1.[INCIDENT__ID]
```

My select:

```
SELECT
    CONTRACT_View.AVILABLE_ENTITLEMENT, 
    CONTRACT_View.INCIDENT__ID 
FROM
    CONTRACT_View
WHERE
    INCIDENT__ID =528770
```

Comment: what is data type of table2.objid ? you pass it as a number in your view, and you pass it as a string in your last select

Comment: Its Interger Datatype.

Comment: Could you please provide table structure and sample data of table 1 and 2?

Comment: Table1-OBJID(Int),Title(String)    Table2 -OBJID(Int) ,table2Rel-Int

Comment: And example data? Is ObjID in Table1 unique? How many matches (in your given example) exist in Table2?

Comment: Yes ID is unique for table1 & table 2