# Separated by Comma in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Could any one please help regarding issue in SQL Server I have a query which returns 4 counts with different Objid. I want to merge them based on objid & value separated with a comma (`,`)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please post what you've tried so far.

Comment: Post the code, text in the question itself. Don't post links to images. SQL Server 2017 added a STRING_AGG method. SQL Server 2016 added STRING_SPLIT. There are a lot of duplicates that show how to do the same with earlier versions

Comment: DON'T DO THIS THIS! Never ever **ever** store delimited data in an sql column.

Comment: This is what i tried but facing other issue thats why i want it in differnt manner.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46954303/duplicate-record-in-sql-server